# position div from the left of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div tag with absolute positioning like

```
 <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1009;top:8%;left:90%;cursor:pointer;">
<a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">&#9660;</a>
    <div id="button" style="border:1px solid blue">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hidden Cameras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CCTV Cameras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employee Theft</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Helpful Hints</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

which is
[image]

how can i make the div to appear in left of anchor tag

like [image] but below the anchor tag

Comment: Sort out your markup. Spans are inline elements, they shouldn't contain block elements, I.E divs. Also don't style inline, use a stylesheet.

Comment: @oGeez ok i will do it

Comment: small inline CSS is ok also if it is not used for other elements or pages.

Comment: I've read this question three times and am still not sure what you're after :(

Comment: @ExtPro sorry for my english,its a drop down menu i want it to appear left of anchor tag as in secound pic(from ie)

Comment: you need to learn about position:relative and how it affects nested absolutely positioned elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but this might work:

```
#button {
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/E3Wtp/

Let me know if I'm completely misunderstanding what you want to do.